# Using pyserial to transfer data via XRF

Tags: python, wireless, serial

I have a small python program that writes a 4 digit number to the serial port every second, using pyserial. I have connected an XRF module (from CISECO) to the sending pi and another XRF to another pi. However when I try and loop `port.read()` on the receiving pi, I get weird output: `'\xe0\'` and `'\x00\'`. Where has my intelligible data gone? How can I read it sensibly?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this issue is because my baud rates on the two XRF modules were out of range. You may also get this same issue if the baud rates are mismatched.